# Firefox 91 "invisible" to screen sharing (Google Meet, Zoom, Slack etc)

Tags: firefox, 21.04, zoom-meeting, slack, google-hangouts

I'm on Ubuntu 21.04 and ever since Firefox 91 came out, I've lost the ability to share a Firefox window on all screen sharing applications.

- The Firefox window simply isn't listed in the set of available windows to share, and
- If I try sharing the entire screen then the Firefox window either appears completely black (Meet, Slack), or initially appears as a background on Zoom with the caveat that as soon as you click on it then it hides itself immediately.

I've tried following the common advice about Ctrl+i and changing permissions of "Share The Screen" away from "block", but it doesn't make any difference.

I get that Firefox has tried to beef up security in 91, but this is just crazy...

I have colleagues using Windows & Firefox 91 who don't seem to report the same problem and so this might be an Ubuntu-only issue.

Short of abandoning Firefox completely, is there a way to allow Firefox to be shared?

Comment: Are you using Wayland Session? Can you logout and choose the X.Org session and check if this issue persists there?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi You probably hit the nail: 21.04 indeed puts you on Wayland, even when upgrading.

Comment: Logging out and switching to xorg (using the cog icon in the bottom right corner) indeed solved the problem. Thanks!